# Do multiple Gray Merchant of Asphodels trigger each others' enters-the-battlefield effects?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If there is a [Gray Merchant of Asphodel](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gray%20Merchant%20of%20Asphodel) on the battlefield and a second [Gray Merchant of Asphodel](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gray%20Merchant%20of%20Asphodel) enters, do both cards trigger and opponent loses x life where x is devotion times 2, or does just the one card entering the battlefield trigger?

Answer (score 1):

No, only the one entering the battlefield triggers.

Any time you see a card use its own name in its rules text, that means it is referring to the card that it is printed on; not other cards with the same name.

> 201.4. Text that refers to the object it's on by name means just that particular object and not any other objects with that name, regardless of any name changes caused by game effects.

Comment: Because "When Gray Merchant of Asphodel enters the battlefield," is far more readable than "When the object on which this ability resides enters the battlefield,"

Comment: @ikegami Do you know why they didn't just use "When this enters the battlefield"?

Comment: I was going to say "because abilities don't enter the battlefield", but some keyword abilities use "When this permanent is ...".